# Why is Spring security JdbcUserDetailsManager not transactional?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Looking at the update and delete functionality in **spring security** "`org.springframework.security.provisioning.JdbcUserDetailsManager`". They are not `transactional` and they do multiple updates as part of a method call.

Why is it not transactional? For eg, the methods implemented from the "UserDetailsManager" interface do deletes and updates within a single method call. Should they not be transactional?

Or it is the responsibility of the caller to invoke them in a transaction?

Comment: A wild guess would be that Security is important where databases not support transactions.

Answer (score 0):

The methods inside `JdbcUserDetailsManager` are not `@Transactional` because the applications should call those methods from within a `@Transacional` block themselves. It's easier for an application to add that requirement than it is to remove it.

Comment: That could be one of the reasons (as I have outlined as well in the question too). However, do you know if there is official Spring Doc, stating that "should be called in a transaction"? Just curious.

Comment: What I have seen in tutorials and production implementations is sometimes without a transaction. And the reasoning is that Spring does not do it so why should we.

Comment: I think it is not stated in any doc that it should be called inside a transaction because it is up to the application requirement to decide whether it should be transactional or not. I asked a Spring Security team member about this question before posting the answer